# Lighweight (no framework) ORM mappyer

Tags: php, orm

I'm looking for a really lightweight and simple ORM for php. I had a look at propel/doctrine as part of symfony and it is just way to complicated for my needs. I am not doing any sort of MVC model and I dont want to use any other frameworks. I have looked at fuelphp and similar for example

The best I could see was NotORM but I was concerned that there didn't seem to be much documentation or any sort of active forum. It seemed neglected

Can anyone recommend an ORM suitable for my needs please?  i want a set of classes for getting individual rows or groups of rows. I would like query classes with query methods/chaining that can traverse relationships. I don't need an MVC framework. I would also like to be able to have classes generated for views. I would also like to be able to run my own custom sql queries if the classes wont let me do what I want and possibly stored procedures. Good documentation and examples are also a plus!! I would be using NOT ORM now if i ad been able to find more tutorials

I Just something to avoid my having to write prepared statements and concatenate sql queries myself. Also something with support and an active forum would be the nice :) The shallowest learing curve in the world would also be nice. I'm used to using .net wrappers and they are really easy. I can jut create the classes without needing all this surrounding framework like symfony which i dont know

I think i also say this but it looked old and unsupported. However that would suit my needs :)
http://www.schizofreend.nl/Pork.dbObject

Many thanks in advance for sharing your wisdom and expertise

Answer (score 1):

What about [PHP Data objects](http://hu1.php.net/pdo)?

Excerpt from the official documentation:

> The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent
>   interface for accessing databases in PHP.

I was using it a lot before switching to Doctrine and it was working fine.

Comment: I use them now. I was hoping more to get one class per table type set up and not have to write queries. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use Propel as a stand-alone ORM (i.e. without Symphony) for large and small projects.  While it does provide lots of functionality you only use the bits you need.

http://propelorm.org

Comment: I tried to use propel as per the instructions on the website but it seemned a right nightmare and all the  relative paths on the installer were wrong i yhink

Comment: can you point me to a really good tutorial on just using the propel part. I was using xampp if that makes any difference. But there were 3 of us and we gave up in then end as it shouoldnt be that much trouble

Comment: This is a good start with regard to installing Propel: http://rapidsol.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/install-propel-ubuntu-in-3-steps.html
And then build a project from an existing database with these commands: http://rapidsol.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/propel-tutorial.html
Does that help?